# Error while trying to backup site files

Tags: backup, tar, centos8

```
# tar -czf /backup/backup.tar.gz /var/www/html
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2020/02: file changed as we read it
# ls -la
total 17160456
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root          58 Feb 26 07:53 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root root        4096 Feb 14 21:19 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 15950548376 Feb 26 08:11 backup.tar.gz
```

I got this error while trying to make my files backup the website is has images uploaded to it constantly so... there is no other way without this error.

Is this backup ok or this error means the backup is not correct and can't be used ?

Comment: this is not an error, it says only the file changed while you were doing the backup.

Comment: so the backup i made is ok ?